# hudson show maven site documentation

Tags: maven-2, hudson

is there a way to show the icon for maven site documentation if using a freestlye project (I switched to a freestyle project rather than maven2 project because of certain bugs - i.e. cobertura graph not showing up on front page, double unit test coverage counting when running cobertura)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always declare it as an artifact to archive ( `**/target/site/**`).

---

**Update**

The newly released [DocLinks plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/DocLinks+Plugin) seems to do what you need.

[Doclinks plugin screenshot http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/7372/projects.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/7372/projects.png)

Comment: i will try that. on a related note, do you know if it is possible to declare zip files as artifacts to archive? i tried that and hudson choked.

Comment: It really should be possible - you can archive jars. Perhaps the zip files are very large? Nevertheless, if it does not work, it's a bug.

Comment: so I tried with the site/** but the it shows all of the html links under the artifacts. what I really want is to do is show the link to the main page.

Comment: How about setting a link in the build description to workspace/site?

Comment: I can try that. I noticed that when using a maven2 project, hudson automatically creates a site directory in the main under .hudson/jobs/<project>. I wonder if there's any way to emulate that.

Comment: I'm going to try adding a task after the build to create that for me.

Comment: That worked, except I can't figure out how hudson configured the http://myserver:8080/hudson/job/<job-name>/site/ link to point to the correct directory.

Comment: Last comment here - I ended up just setting up another job for generating the site documentation that runs less frequently anyway.